# prevent div from scrolling despite position: absolute

Tags: css

I am facing a bit of a 'div hell'. This is the html snippet:

```
<div id="xyz" class="sensoricon moveable type1 node-2-sensor-1 string1" style="position: absolute; top: 241.467px; left: 236.417px; opacity: 1;">
<img src="/content/images/shared/sensors/bla.png" alt="">
</div>
```

I understand that:

```
position: absolute;
```

should prevent the div from scrolling, but it still does (although only a little bit at the beginning). Can anyone see anything generally wrong?

Comment: No. `position: fixed;` prevent the div from scrolling

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
position: fixed;
```

Because **position: absolute;** sets position relative to parent coordinates and when the document is scrolled, absolute position is STILL relative to parent's and parents (through whatever count of levels) is relative to whole document position.

On the other hand **position: fixed** sets position relative to window's and not document's. That way your element stays in the same place when scrolled.

Comment: It seems that `position fixed` works perfectly on mobile safari but not on android browser.

Answer (score 3):

Like i said in my comment:
You should use `position: fixed`.
It is similar to `absolute`, but it don't scroll with the whole site, it is "fixed" on the given position.

Answer (score 0):

absolute positioning means a positioning measured at the edge of the next higher ancestor element that has not the position static